# Swagger open and giving a error in .NET 6 MacOS Visual Studio 2022 preview 1

Tags: asp.net, macos, swagger, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

[image]

```
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultTagsSelector(ApiDescription apiDescription)
  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.ITagsMetadata' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultSortKeySelector(ApiDescription apiDescription)
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
     at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
     at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
     at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`2.GetEnumerator()
     at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.ITagsMetadata' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultTagsSelector(ApiDescription apiDescription)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultSortKeySelector(ApiDescription apiDescription)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`2.GetEnumerator()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Visual Studio preview 3 and the exact 6.0.100 .net version (working for M1 chip as well)

Comment: Thanks, Chanaka. This worked perfectly.